# Twitter Character Counting

Tags: twitter, textbox, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to implement a remaining character count feature for Twitter Twitt TextBox in Windows Phone 8 & Windows store 8.1.

Twitter limits Tweet length to 140 characters.If Textbox Text length exceeds 140 char,I'm not allowing user to twitt that text message.

If user enters any URLs in textBox,twitter api considers that Url length as 22 or 23.

How to implement a remaining character count feature with Urls?.If any method is available in Twiteer Api?

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters
https://dev.twitter.com/overview/t.co

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to say, it was fun to work out the answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of simple, and surprisingly difficult.

So, I solved this with a behavior; I call it the SocialTextBoxBehavior.

> You can download the source here: http://codepaste.net/j4ry9v

It easily supports a UI like this:

[image]

> I certainly tested it to make sure it works. It seems to.

I added some nice properties you can bind back to your viewmodel:

1. MaxLength - you would likely set this to 140
2. MinLength - this is up to you, it defaults to 5
3. UrlLength - in your question you indicated 22 or 23 (it's a scalar value)
4. CurrentLength - current, adjusted text length; this is updated as the user types
5. CurrentRemaining - current, adjusted remaining; this is updated as the user types
6. IsValid - ensuring CurrentLength is between constraints; this is updated as the user types

The syntax to use the behavior is pretty straight-forward. I hope you think so.

Like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:SocialTextBoxBehavior x:Name="TwitterBehavior" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,10" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TwitterBehavior}">
        <Run Text="{Binding CurrentLength}" />
        <Run Text="character(s) typed." />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="{Binding RemainingLength}" />
        <Run Text="character(s) remaining." />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="{Binding MaxLength}" />
        <Run Text="character(s) limit." />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="Can submit? " />
        <Run Text="{Binding IsValid}" />
    </TextBlock>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid, ElementName=TwitterBehavior}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Best of luck!